# EXCEL - When I run SUM(COUNTIFS) and then run IF (AND) functions on the same range using the same parameters, I get different totals. Why?

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I wanted to double-check the accuracy of some work I’m doing. I have a column where I am returning unique student IDs using this formula `=IF(AND(B2="Eligible/Previously Eligible",E2<TODAY()-1095),A2,"")`. When I count up the number of values returned, I get 931. However, if I use this formula `=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,"Eligible/Previously Eligible",E:E,"<"&TODAY()-1095))` to count the number of IDs that match the criteria, I get 759. I don’t understand what I’ve done wrong to get a different answer since the criteria for both formula seems to be the same. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Your first formula is referencing column A, though you haven't told us what's in that column yet.

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you have an additional `SUM` function in your second formula, which is redundant. Perhaps a small example dataset (10 rows or so) together with expected result would help?

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks. While working to edit and clean up what I was asking, I realize that the problem are blank dates. What do I need to do to this formula `COUNTIFS(B:B,"Eligible/Previously Eligible",E:E,'<"&TODAY()-1095))` to also exclude blank cells in the E:E range?